# How to get matches of user by steamid?

Tags: match, steam

by this link you can get all matches from Dota 2 
https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_205790/GetMatchHistory/v001/?key=***************

but how to get matches of **one single user** by steamid?

Comment: @Andy account_id!=steamid

Comment: @Andy how to find account_id by username or by link (http://steamcommunity.com/id/URLNAME) or by profile_id http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/******?

Comment: I added a link to my answer on how to get profile id from URL name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is convert the STEAM ID to a PROFILE ID. This can be accomplished using something like the [Steam Condenser](https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-php) project, more simply this [function](https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-php/blob/master/lib/steam/community/SteamId.php#L117) from the Steam Condenser project. If you just use this function, you'll have to modify the exceptions thrown as the `SteamCondenserException` won't exist. If you have the unique player ID, I suggest using the entire Steam Condenser project and looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539857/php-pdo-steam-api/22543055#22543055).

```
/**
* Converts a SteamID as reported by game servers to a 64bit numeric
* SteamID as used by the Steam Community
*
* @param string $steamId The SteamID string as used on servers, like
* <var>STEAM_0:0:12345</var>
* @return string The converted 64bit numeric SteamID
* @throws SteamCondenserException if the SteamID doesn't have the correct
* format
*/
    public static function convertSteamIdToCommunityId($steamId) {
        if($steamId == 'STEAM_ID_LAN' || $steamId == 'BOT') {
            throw new SteamCondenserException("Cannot convert SteamID \"$steamId\" to a community ID.");
        }
        if (preg_match('/^STEAM_[0-1]:[0-1]:[0-9]+$/', $steamId)) {
            $steamId = explode(':', substr($steamId, 8));
            $steamId = $steamId[0] + $steamId[1] * 2 + 1197960265728;
            return '7656' . $steamId;
        } elseif (preg_match('/^\[U:[0-1]:[0-9]+\]$/', $steamId)) {
            $steamId = explode(':', substr($steamId, 3, strlen($steamId) - 1));
            $steamId = $steamId[0] + $steamId[1] + 1197960265727;
            return '7656' . $steamId;
        } else {
            throw new SteamCondenserException("SteamID \"$steamId\" doesn't have the correct format.");
        }
    }
```

Now that you have the 64bit ID, you can pass this to the API call you are already making. It will get passed to the `account_id` parameter.

In PHP, you will end up with something like this:

```
$matches = 10;    // Return last 10 matches
$acct = convertSteamIdToCommunityId(STEAMIDYOUARECHECKING);
$APIKEY = <YOURKEYHERE>;

$steamurl = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/V001/?key=$APIKEY&account_id=$acct&Matches_Requested=$matches&format=json";
$json_object= file_get_contents($steamurl);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_object;
```

The three variables at the top of that snippet are for you to fill in with the number of matches you want returned, the Steam ID you are checking and the API KEY you are using. Your results will be in the `$json_object` and are for you to parse.

Comment: for example my link is http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198125073633/
how to get account_id?